# Replace wordpress slug title with metabox value in permalink

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, meta-boxes

I have a custom post type for minutes of the meetings without a title. I wish that the permalink was something like *www.website.com/minutes/2018-10-16/* in witch *minutes* is the registered custom post type name and *2018-10-16* is the metabox whit the meeting date (that I already created).
Ho can I do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by following [this tutorial](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33551/how-to-rewrite-uri-of-custom-post-type/33555?fbclid=IwAR0HIVyI0SLRZpxpFvvtleRhoVpg4ALQUPC5sJXWa_37KcyoJl-wRvuRoXI).

This is the code posted by Milo for a custom post type called "product":

```
add_filter('post_type_link', 'wpse33551_post_type_link', 1, 3);

function wpse33551_post_type_link( $link, $post = 0 ){
    if ( $post->post_type == 'product' ){
        return home_url( 'product/' . $post->ID );
    } else {
        return $link;
    }
}

add_action( 'init', 'wpse33551_rewrites_init' );

function wpse33551_rewrites_init(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'product/([0-9]+)?$',
        'index.php?post_type=product&p=$matches[1]',
        'top' );
}
```